# Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate in lme4 for ratio data

Tags: r, lme4

My data is ratio data. So I'm trying to use `lme4()` with a binomial model to analyze it.

Here is my code:

```
fate.reP = glmer(predated~type+(1|island),data=fate.rate,family="binomial")
```

Here is a sample set of data:

```
type    cluster  tree   predated
 B        B7-1    1       0.48  
 B        B7-1    2       0.66
 B        B7-2    3       0.18
 M         I63    8       0.55
 M         I63    9       0.6
 M         I63   20       0.41
 M         I63   21       0.42
 S         I14    5       0.75
 S         I14   17       0.53
 S         I15    6       0.23
 S         I15    7       0.03
```

When I run the model, it shows that :

```
Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
In addition: Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

Are there errors in my data, or any other errors?
I am using R 3.0.3 for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning `non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!` gives you the hint that binomial responses in `lme4` must be *integers*.  I don't see the denominators (i.e. total number of individuals exposed to predation) anywhere here: if you have them in your data set as (e.g.) `total_exposed`, you can use

```
fate.reP <- glmer(predated~type+(1|island),
     data=fate.rate,family="binomial",
     weights=total_exposed)
```

The behaviour of `lme4` is a little bit different from `glm` in base R, which will warn you but still produce results if `glm` is non-integer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have solved this problem.I have another question: if there are many 0 value in my data, can I use the Generalized linear mixed model for my data? For instance, in my sample data, the predated value has many 0 value, will the function glmer() run successfully?

Comment: A binomial model should work fine with zeros.  If there are many more zeros than predicted from the model (i.e. a zero-inflated or zero-altered model), then the model will still work but the fit may not be very good.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer. I am a newer of R language, So could you give me some detail suggestions for zero-inflated model? Is this method different from GLMM? Or just a adaption to GLMM?